# Angular sass compilation undefinded variable

Tags: angular, sass

I have a problem with my Angular app. Since I serve my application on every first run and on every change made in html files, I get an undefined variable error. When I save any scss file, the error disappears until the next changes in any html file.
I store my scss variables in a separate file that is predefined with _, and I import it to the root file without this underscore at the very beginning of the file.

[angular.json styles part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8etz.png)

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ7x8.png)